# Symfony transform ChoiceType in CheckboxType

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I've problem with my form type. I have an entity activity and an other entity class. It's in *ManyToMany*. When I display the form, it's in `ChoiceType`, but I want it to be in `CheckboxType`. So I've :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('libelle')
        ->add('horraire')
        ->add('horraireDebut')
        ->add('horraireFin')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('classes');
}
```

It display a `ChoiceType` but I want a `CheckboxType`, so I changed this to :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('libelle')
        ->add('horraire')
        ->add('horraireDebut')
        ->add('horraireFin')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('classes', CheckboxType::class);
}
```

But this only displays one checkbox while I have several recordings (which appears well with the first code).

My form.html.twig :

```
<div class="form-group{% if form.classes.vars.errors|length %} has-error{% endif %}">
<label for="{{ form.classes.vars.id }}" class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right required">Classes <span class="red">*</span></label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    {{ form_widget(form.classes,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.classes) }}
</div>
```

How can I get a checkbox line or a checkbox dropdown ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you need? You say "checkbox line or checkbox dropdown", but I'm not sure what this means. If you add a picture of what you need that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `multiple` and `expanded` options together to achieve this ([Ref](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#expanded)):

```
$builder->add('classes', null, array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
));
```

Then checkboxes will be rendered.

Note that `null` value mean `EntityType::class` in case you use Doctrine ORM. Otherwise, use `EntityType::class` and `'class' => Entity::class` option.

Comment: Please, accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you're looking for, you could also try the EntityType with a query builder:

```
->add('classes', EntityType::class, array(
    'by_reference' => true,
    'multiple' => true,   
    'expanded' => false,   
    'class'    => 'AppBundle\Entity\Class',
    'property' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
            $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
            return $qb->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
         }
    ))
```